# Python: "inline" block / condition to return a char?

Tags: python, return, conditional-statements

I would like to create a string that uses a plural if count > 1.

For that, I would like have an "inline" condition that returns 's' to concatenate to my noun.

```
print "The plural of plural is plural{0}. {1}".format( {'s' if count > 1}, "Isnt't it!?")
```

Comment: Note that if you are working on a more general solution, you will also need to take words with irregular plural into account, e.g. "child" -> "children", and if you aim for an internationalized version, even more things might need to change in the sentence than just a single word.

Comment: have a look at inflect.py to convert English words to their plurals.
easy_install inflect.py
or
pip install inflect
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/inflect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to add the else part to the `'s' if count > 1` otherwise this is not a valid expression** (because the value to return when `count <= 1` has not been specified and Python cannot guess what this should be):

```
print "The plural of plural is plural{0}. {1}".format(
    's' if count > 1 else '', "Isnt't it!?")
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Python 2.4?

Comment: to answer my own comment, it seems like {{{ count > 1 and 's' or '' }}} works.

Answer (score 1):

```
print "The plural of plural is plural{0}. {1}".format('s' if count > 1 else '', "Isnt't it!?")
```